# Pattern matching error on instance declaration

Tags: haskell, instance, monads

I need to declare a Monad instance for an specific data type:

```
data M m a = Mk (m (Maybe a))

instance (Monad m) => Monad (M m) where
  return x = Mk (m (Just x))
  Mk (m (Nothing)) >>= f = Mk (m (Nothing))
  Mk (m (Just x)) >>= f = f x
```

But I get:

```
test.hs:6:7: Parse error in pattern: m
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

It may be very simple, but I cant figure it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type variable `m` is not something you can pattern match on, especially not in order to distinguish between `Just` and `Nothing`. Think about what it would mean for different possible types used in place of `m`--in many cases, such a pattern match would be outright impossible.

To write that instance, you'll need something like this:

```
instance (Monad m) => Monad (M m) where
  return x = Mk (return (Just x))
  Mk mx >>= f = -- ??
```

Note the `return` used to create a value of type `m (Maybe a)`--that's possible because of the `Monad m` constraint, and in the general case (with no constraint at all) there'd be no way to create such a value.

To implement `(>>=)` you'll need to do something similar, likewise making use of `(>>=)` for the `Monad` instance of `m`.

Incidentally, you should consider using a `newtype` for `M`, unless you have a specific reason for wanting `data`. Most of the time, if you *can* use `newtype`, you should.

Answer (score 0):

You can only pattern match on a constructor, not on anything else. You'll have to use the Monad instance for m to get to the Maybe data that's inside. I'm not 100% sure that this has the behavior you want, but it does typecheck.

```
data M m a = Mk (m (Maybe a))

instance (Monad m) => Monad (M m) where
  return x = Mk (return (Just x))
  Mk m >>= f = Mk (m >>= go)
    where go (Just x) = let Mk x' = f x in x'
          go _        = return Nothing
```

Comment: Thnaks both of you!! Now I understood what I was doing wrong!